# How can the Community user approve suggested edits?

Tags: support, faq, editing, community-user

I see that the [Community](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user is not a real person, but only a background process. I was just curious to know that how can a process decide whether the suggested edit by the user should be approved/rejected.
Because, if the edit is about grammatical correction of a question, it will require a very good program to process the suggestion and judge it. As per my knowledge, it will require high level of Artificial Intelligence to be implemented for this process. Is it implemented for the process-Community?

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens in those cases is that:

- A user reviewed the suggested post, and (instead of choosing *Approve*, or *Reject*) selected *Improve*.

  [image: screenshot]
- The same user improved the suggested edit, and selected "Suggested edit was helpful" (which is selected by default).

  [image: screenshot]

Stack Exchange software sees this as if:

- The suggested edit has been approved
- The post has been edited to be improved

  [image: screenshot]

The first operation is arbitrary attributed to the Community user, but it should be attributed to the user who clicked on the "improve" button. The Community user is shown for "historical" reasons, and because there are sites where a single user cannot approve/reject a suggested edit, such as on Stack Overflow, where two users are required.

The proposed edits that are automatically rejected show a warning when they are submitted; that is what happens, for example, for suggested edits that change just a single character. That is the only moment when code checks the suggested edit.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation! I got my all doubts cleared by this answer :)